# Issues unmarshalling POJO

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

There's a webservice that has 3 java objects that I need to retrieve. These are the objects

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="licenseFile")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class XmlLicenseFile implements Cloneable
    {
        //URI Info
        public static final String URI_PATH = "licenseFiles";
        @XmlAttribute
        private String url;

        //Base License Info
        private String licenseFileId;
        private String licenseStatus; 
        private String licenseFileType; 
        private String licenseFileVersion;

        //Request Info
        private String requestSource;
        private String locale;
        private Boolean overrideErrors;
        private String internallyRequestingUserId;
        private String requestorUserProfileId;
        private String externalIpAddress;
        private Boolean internalUseOnly;

        //Contract Info
        private String serviceId; //Used to be called contractNumber
        private String contractAdminName;
        private String contractAdminEmail;
        private String organizationName;
        private String contractStartDate;
        private String contractEndDate;
        private Boolean overdraftAllowed;
        private String vlaType;
        private Integer vlaLogAutoSendFrequency;

        //Server Info
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="licenseServers")
        @XmlElement(name="licenseServer")
        private List<XmlLicenseServer> licenseServers;

        //License Package Info
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="licensePackages")
        @XmlElement(name="licensePackage")
        private List<XmlLicensePackage> licensePackages;

        //Error Info
        private String errorType; 
        private Integer errorCode;
        private String errorDescription;

        //Database Info
        private String creationDate;
        private String lastUpdateDate;

        //License Content
        private String licenseFileName;
        private String licenseFileContent;

        public String getOrganizationName() {
        return organizationName;
        }
        public void setOrganizationName(String organizationName) {
        this.organizationName = organizationName;
        }
        // ALL OF THE OTHER SETTERS AND GETTERS GO HERE
 }   

@XmlRootElement(name="licensePackage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlLicensePackage 
{
    //URI Info
    public static final String URI_PATH = "licensePackages";
    @XmlAttribute
    private String url;

    //Base Package Info
    private String licensePackageId;
    private String licenseFileId;
    private String packageStatus; 


    private String partNumber;

    //Package Info
    private String packageName;
    private String packageVersion; //Calculated
    private String operatingSystem; //Can be calculated or passed in

    //Generation Info
    private String serialNumber;
    private Integer seatCount;
    private String packageExpireDate;

    //Client/Concurrency Info
    private String concurrencyType; 
    private String clientType; 

    //Reconciliation Info
    private String productReconciliationId;

    //Error Info
    private String errorType; 
    private Integer errorCode;
    private String errorDescription;

    //Database Info
    private String creationDate;
    private String lastUpdateDate;
        //ALL THE GETTERS AND SETTERS
}

@XmlRootElement(name="licenseServer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlLicenseServer
{
    private String serverName;
    private String computerId;
    //ALL SETTERS AND GETTERS HERE
}
```

My issue is with the getter. Here's the GET code. The client variable is a jersey client.

```
public static XmlLicenseFile getLicenseFile(String key){
        XmlLicenseFile returnedFile = null;
        URI uri = constructURIByFileId(key); //THIS CREATES THE URI, AND I'VE CONFIRMED IT'S CORRECT
        try{
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri.toString());
            returnedFile = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(XmlLicenseFile.class);
            if(returnedFile == null){
                throw new ProviderException(ResponseErrorType.NOT_FOUND, "The license file doesn't exists", "", "");
            } //TODO Fill error cases
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e);
            throw new ProviderException(ResponseErrorType.INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR, "Internal Server Error", "", "");
        }
        return returnedFile;
    }
```

Everytime I try to run the code, it fails in the webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).accept(XmlLicenseFile.class) part. It fails with a ClientException. Any idea why is it failing with the unmarshalling?

--EDIT--
Here's the URI that's being built
localhost/myWS/1.0/licenseFiles/EBB080CCFB02309AE0440021287E6A9E

If I hit that URL in the browser, it returns the valid licenseFile.

Comment: What is the exception? PLease add that to your question.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Comment: Could you paste the whole stack trace in the question. It appears that there is something else wrong.

Comment: Turned out to be that the URI didn't have the http:// at the beginning, and it was failing. Once I added that, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that the URI didn't have the "http://" part. Once I added that, it all worked! :D